# Can YEAR() be used to with a DATETIME as it can with DATE [e.g. YEAR(Datetime__c)]

Tags: formula, datetime

SFDC Documentations tells me YEAR "Returns the year component of a Datetime in the local time zone of the context user".

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm

When I try to use "`YEAR(Datetime__c)`" in a workflow criteria I recieve error...

> "Incorrect parameter type for function 'YEAR()'. Expected Date,
>   received DateTime"

Can YEAR() be used to with a DATETIME as it can with DATE [e.g. `YEAR(Datetime__c)`]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using:

```
YEAR(DATEVALUE(Datetime__c))
```

You are correct, `YEAR()` can not be used with a DateTime object. You need to convert that DateTime object to a Date beforehand using the [`DATEVALUE()`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_functions.htm) formula.

Comment: That works - Thanks! I guess I can reach out SFDC why their documentation says otherwise.

Comment: Their documentation is correct. You are looking at methods on the DateTime class in Apex. What you should be looking at are the formula functions - http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_functions.htm - Look under the Date and Time Functions section